# How can I run a static initializer method in C# before the Main() method?

Tags: c#, .net, static-methods, static-classes, static-initialization

Given a static class with an initializer method:

```
public static class Foo
{
    // Class members...

    internal static init()
    {
        // Do some initialization...
    }
}
```

How can I ensure the initializer is run before `Main()`?

The best I can think of is to add this to `Foo`:

```
private class Initializer
{
    private static bool isDone = false;
    public Initializer()
    {
        if (!isDone)
        {
            init();
            isDone = true;
        }
    }
}

private static readonly Initializer initializer = new Initializer();
```

Will this work or are there some unforeseen caveats? And is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure but it could be that application domains could solve your problem. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s0z09xw.aspx)

Comment: @LueTm Interesting. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply do the initialization inside a [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) for `Foo`.

From the documentation:

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class
>   before the first instance is created or any static members are
>   referenced.

Answer (score 14):

There are [static constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) in C# that you can use.

```
public static class Foo
{
    // Class members...

    static Foo(){
        init();
        // other stuff
    }

    internal static init()
    {
        // Do some initialization...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Move your code from an `internal static` method to a [`static` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors), like this:

```
public static class Foo
{
  // Class members...

  static Foo()
  {
    // Do some initialization...
  }
}
```

This way, you are quite sure that the static constructor will be run on first mention of your `Foo` class, whether it's a construction of an instance or access to a static member.

Answer (score 5):

Place your initialization code in the static constructor of the class

```
static Foo()
{
    // Initialization code
}
```

This constructor is run the first time the class is accessed.

You can use `RunClassConstructor` to trigger the static constructor of the class before using a class. This can be useful if, for instance, this class registers itself in a IOC container or something like this.

```
RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(Foo).TypeHandle);
```

You find the `RuntimeHelpers` in the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace.

---

**C# 9.0** added [Module Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/module-initializers) allowing you to write initialization code for the assembly with no need to explicitly call anything.

Apply the `[ModuleInitializer]` attribute to a static void parameterless method to make it a module initializer.

```cs
[ModuleInitializer]
internal static void MyAssemblyInitializer()
{
    // ...
}
```